# highstockchart range selector x axis date is displaying only jan 8 1970 to jan 19 1970

Tags: python, django, highcharts

i have a data's from 1931 to yesterday in db. i am using python django models for getting data and disply the highstock. the chart is displaying only particular 15 days in x axis and range selector is also not working. here i have attached the jsfiddle code for your refernece.....any help thatks a lot ...strucked in this issues for last 2 days....

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
      chart: {
          type: 'line'
      },
      rangeSelector: {
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            selected: 2
        },
      title: {
          text: '% of S&P 500 members above their 50 dma'
      },

```
  yAxis: [{
    lineWidth: 1,
    height :100,
    opposite: true,
    tickposition:'outside',

    visible:true

  }, {
    lineWidth: 0,
    height :100,
    opposite: true,
    tickposition:'outside',
    top :170,
    visible:true,


  }],

  series: [{
      yAxis: 0,
      name: 'S&P 500',
      data: {{ sp500_series }},
      color: 'green',
      tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }

  }, {
      yAxis: 1,
      xAxis:0,
      y :-30,
      name: 'dma50',
      data: {{ dma50_series }},
      color: 'red',
      tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }

  }]
```

});

the data samples are

series: [{
          yAxis: 0,
          name: 'S&P 500',
          data: [
 [
  637266600.0,
  336.0
 ],
 [
  637353000.0,
  336.87
 ],
 [
  637439400.0,
  338.07
 ],
 [
  637525800.0,
  341.91
 ],
 [
  637785000.0,
  343.53
 ],
 [
  637871400.0,
  341.57
 ],
.......
........
......

my output is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoBb7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct. Highcharts uses Unix Timestamp in milliseconds for dates. Your first sample x value: `637266600.0` is `Thu Jan 08 1970 09:01:06 GMT+0000`

For example `0` is `Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0000`, so for previous dates you need to use negative values.

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6y3znsma/